# How to prevent Safari from opening iTunes Links immediately in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

Often I just want to read the info about an iPhone app, so I click on a link. But then, the apple pages that contains the info immediately launches iTunes. It's so incredibly annoying. And then, iTunes is so lame that it doesn't even allow to open things in a new window. It's a crippled web browser. So what I try to do in iTunes when browsing the app store is this: Right click > "Copy Link" and then open that in Safari. And now guess what happens: Safari immediately kicks the link back to iTunes and it takes me away from my search results to the app info page.

Can I switch that "feature" off?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't about switching the feature off, but you could try browsing the iTunes store in your web browser via:

http://app-store.appspot.com

Comment: Although a nice idea, the implementation seriously sucks ;-)

Comment: True; it's pretty ugly.